# Convert Datatable as Enumerable to List(Of String)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have datatable dt in the following line of code:

```
Dim str As List(Of String) = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(a) New With {.WorkZone = a.Field(Of String)("MarkerWorkZone")}).ToList()
```

ToString is given as an option for the select statement, but I receive the error: Value Type 'List(Of )' cannot be converted to 'List(Of String)'.
Though I understand I am really trying to convert an EnumerableRowCollection.

That said, I was able to convert a similar line of code to a dictionary:

```
Dim di As Dictionary(Of String, String) = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(a) New With {.Code = a.Field(Of String)("AssemblyCode"), .DeficiencyDesc = a.Field(Of String)("AssemblyDeficiencyDesc")}).Distinct().ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Code, Function(x) x.DeficiencyDesc)
```

But the toList() does not have an option to add a function, as does the ToDictionary.

What am I missing with the ToList statement? Is it possible to convert to a list?

Comment: You're creating an Anonymous object in the Select() transformation. Just select `a.Field(Of String)("MarkerWorkZone")` and you have a `List<string>`.

Comment: You could also write something silly as `... dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(a) New With {.WorkZone = a.Field(Of String)("MarkerWorkZone")}.WorkZone).ToList()` :)

Comment: @Jimi Thank you! That worked (I tried your second comment). Now I need to go back and understand exactly why that works.

Comment: Well, what you have there returns a `List(Of a')` (anonymous objects) while you declared the recipient as a `List(Of String)`. The other to methods both select a string, accumulated into a List in the end.

Comment: @Jimi's answer is best. But I've also used a foreach to move data from a DataTable to a List (or HashSet, etc.). It may be easier to write the code using a foreach if there are some conditions, or if there's more than one field in the DataTable.